# YAFBLQ: How to pre-populate FB login and password fields?

Tags: iphone, facebook

Yet another fb login question:

By the time my user has something to share, they've already logged into my app server.
I give them the option to use their FB creds for my app.
So if they share, I want to pre-populate the FB login page with the creds they've already supplied to me.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to do it?

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you actually save their fb credentials?!?

Comment: Well, they're not necessarily FB creds when I save them - the user has to log into my app.  I'm giving them the option to create an account on my app using their FB creds, but now that I'm writing all this out (and seeing everyone's astonishment), I may need to push back on this requirement.  Lemme chat with the boss, and see.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Facebook API too. You **never** keep login and pass in your app (check Facebook API doc). However you can keep session. So the user enter login and pass once. In my code I've a "FacebookLogger" who is a singleton with a Facebook object.

To store session I use NSUserDefaults [(find doc here)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:m_Facebook.accessToken forKey:@"AccessToken"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:m_Facebook.expirationDate forKey:@"ExpirationDate"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Where m_Facebook is my Facebook object in my singleton. After that I can catch Access with :

```
m_Facebook.accessToken    = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"AccessToken"];

m_Facebook.expirationDate = (NSDate *) [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ExpirationDate"];
```

Comment: as this seems the most reasonable approach for now, I'm accepting your answer.  Thanks.